# YII : How to Execute read query database in model but by value from view file

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have a textfield `textfield1` in my form with an automatically filled value. I want to make a function in my model to generate the code for a `textfield2` as ID. And to generate that code, in the my model I need to read from the database with the following query:

```
select * table_a where code=***value from textfield1***
```

This value is located in view/_form. How can I pass the value from view or _form to the model?

My View/Form :

```
// this is the textfield that is filled automatically. I want to it to the model
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'kode'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'kode',array('size'=>40,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'kode'); ?>
</div>

 // this is the text field where I want to fill by query in my model
<div class="">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'kode_primary'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'kode_primary',array('size'=>40,'maxlength'=>255,'value'=>(($model->isNewRecord)? $model->generateKode_P():$model->no),'readOnly'=>'true')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'kode_primary'); ?>
```

My Model :

```
 public function generateKode_P(){
    $connection = yii::app()->db;
    $command=$connection->createCommand("select * from arsip_perihal WHERE kode='I want to get value from another textfield where has generated value located in same view/_Form'");
 }
```

Comment: @AyyanarG Thank you for your support, I has been added my code.

Comment: you can do this while page was loading i.e in $(document).ready using ajax call

Comment: @AyyanarG If using $model->generateKode_P($model->kode) to pass value, it only pass value from model, but I just want to Execute query with select command based value from view/_form before. So how to passing value from view based textfield to model?

Comment: you can do this while page was loading  your view i.e in $(document).ready using ajax call

Comment: Try to make the question understandable

Answer (score 0):

first you have to submit the form, because the server doesn't know about that value, then in your controller catch that value, similar to default `actionCreate()` and `actionUpdate()` functions of your controller.

because you have used active inputs, for example if your models name is `User`, the value will probably be in a `$_POST['User']['kode_primary']` or `$_GET['User']['kode_primary']` variable, depending on what your forms sending method is

it's best to grab that variable by `yii`s default function:

```
$user_attr = Yii::app()->request->getParam('User');
// now you can access it like
$user_attr['kode_primary'];
```